# Use overloading with derived classes for control flow

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I wanted to know if there is any way I can use method overloading to control the program flow.

So my problem is, I have a method which signature I cannot change e.g.:

```
public void Event(Args args) { }
```

Now the class `Args` is containing a reference to an abstract class called `Base`. `Base` can be either the derived classes `A` or `B` at run-time.

Now I want to do different things depending on which derived class is passed. To stay extensible i know there will be more derived classes like `C` and `D` later on, maybe also `Base` is not abstract anymore.

What I do right now to control the program flow is following:

```
public void Event(Args args) {
    if(args.handle is A a) 
        foo(a);
    else if(args.handle is B b)
        foo(b);
}
```

With two different methods of `foo(...)`: `foo(A a)` and `foo(B b)`

Is there any way to get rid of the `if else` statements so the c#-Run-time chooses the correct `foo` based on its most derived class up to the highest non-abstract class (I sure have to implement all of them).

I also cannot change `Base` and make `foo` a virtual method of it.

The Idea is, as you may noticed, that I don't want to change `Event` every time there is a new derived class. I only want to provide an new `foo` method. Or maybe provide one `foo` method for two derived classes with common base and so on.

The complete code looks like this:

```
public abstract class Base{}

public class A : Base {}

public class B : Base {}

public class Args {

    public Base handle = new A();
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Event(new Args());
    }

    public static void foo(A a) {}

    public static void foo(B b) {}


    public static void Event(Args args) {
        foo(args.handle); // here the error occures 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire point of polymorhism is to enable runtime-binding for the actual calls. So if you have this methods:

```
Foo(A a) { ... }
Foo(B b) { ... }
```

and call it like this:

```
Foo((Base)args.handle);
```

the runtime choses the most decent (that is the most specific) overload. You don´t need to switch on the actual type yourself.

EDIT: You also need a method for the case when the events `Handler` is neither `A` nor `B`:

```
Foo(Base b) { ... }
```

Comment: Do you mean `Foo((Base)args.base)`?

Comment: I alos get the error: "Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Base' to 'A'"

Comment: I can´t see where you try to up-cast a `Base` to `A`. Maybe you should provide where you get that error.

Comment: I get the error for this line: `Foo((Base)args.base)` args.base is of type `Base`

Comment: Well, you surely also need a function for the base-class if it is instantiable (that is not `abstract`). How else should `Foo(new Base())` be resolved?

Comment: Ah sorry, I shouldn't have called it `base`, because base is a reserved keyword... Args has nothing to do with Class Base or A and B ... This lead to the missunderstandinds I wasn't aware of...

Comment: I provided the full source to resolve the misunderstandings

Comment: The runtime does no such thing. In fact the above would be a compiler error as Base cannot be converted to A or B. If you cast to dynamic then the DLR would chose the correct overload but that's a bit heavy. Better to come up with some sort of double dispatch-esque technique

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 care to explain more in detail?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 what do you mean by "the above would be a compiler-error"? I created a fiddle which does compile: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3Z4zZ

Comment: @HimBromBeere but Base isn't abstract in your example and furthermore, the function DoSomething does not get called with new A() or something, a reference of type Base is passed, which is earlier either assigned to A or B, so this won't work

Comment: As you can see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hssyva the "wrong" method gets called

Comment: It was a compiler error before you added the overload that accepted parameter of type Base. But it (the compiler, not the runtime) is still not going to magically pick one. If your call site has an explicit cast to Base, that's the overload it will use.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes I know that, that it won't magically pick one. This was the reason I asked the question if C# provides some additional "magic" like `Foo(downcast_to_most_derived(args.handle))` and then call the right method. The question was not about the compilation error, it is about runtime decision of which overloaded method to use